# Why is Frob$_{l}$ in the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

As I said, I'm not sure how Frob$_{l}$ is supposed to act, in particular I'm interested in how it acts on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$, where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: If $p\nmid l$ then $Frob_l(\sqrt{p})=(-1)^{(p/l)}\sqrt{p}$. There is an indeterminacy at $p=l$ (due to ramification). When extending to the ramified and non-abelian infinite extension $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q}$ there is even more indeterminacy, ie. many possible $Frob_l$. You'll want to construct a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}$ above $l$ and an automorphism $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$ such that $\forall a\in \overline{\Bbb{Z}},\sigma(a) -a^l \in \mathfrak{q}$.